# Getting the content of an xml file and storing the content to a string in order to parse the content

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I tried putting a toast before the return statement but the String variable returns an empty string.

public String getXmlFile(String pathFile, Context context){

```
      String xmlFileString = "";
      AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
      try {
        InputStream str = am.open(pathFile);
        int length = str.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        xmlFileString = new String(data);
      } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
      }

       return xmlFileString;
}
```

Comment: because you never read from the stream

Comment: you are not readinig `InputStream` into `data`

Comment: i have posted the answer try it..

Answer (score 1):

use this to read `byte[]` from `InputStream`:

```
public byte[] convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();

    return sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to read the XML. Without passing UTF-8 to the InputStreamReader you might get a broken XML string.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    context.getAssets().open(pathFile), HTTP.UTF_8));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Now when parsing the string to XML in my case there was also the problem that each line break was interpreted as an own XML node. Spaces also were an issue. Use this on the string read above to fix that:

```
String oneLineXml = sb.toString().replace("\n", "").replaceAll("> +<", "><");
```

Only then you should parse the string, like this:

```
Document xml = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
        oneLineXml.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8))));
```